# Very large terrains in Unreal-4

Tags: terrain, unreal-4

I was watching some YouTube tutorials on making terrains in UE4 and in each one they mention that the larger the terrain the worse the performance gets.
I was wondering what you would do if you wanted to create a map like in skyrim or WOW. Is the terrain made of one massive terrain or is it made up out of a series of terrains in a grid? And is there any optimisation that you can do or is it all handled by UE4?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This link should help](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/405526/how-can-i-create-a-massive-large-scale-terrain-env.html). Although it's about satellite maps, it still answers your question: **UE4 has support for importing tilesets, which is your giant terrain broken up into pieces.**

You could also look [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/LevelStreaming/WorldBrowser/) to find UE4's World Composition tool, which makes it incredibly easier to use a large terrain in your game. (So, to answer the other part of your question, it *is*, in fact, handled by Unreal.